# Fails to Add a new row with generator

Tags: python, pandas

```py
df = pd.read_excel('an_excel.xlsx')

def go(how):
    for h in range(how):
        if h % 2 == 0:
            yield 'equals 0'
        elif h % 2 != 0:
            yield 'equals 1'

for i in go(len(df['Generator Column'])):
    df['new column'] = i
```

I am trying to add a new column by using `go` function even though i add some if else statements which ,works fine, but it only applies the row `'equals 0'` i expect a pattern which is

```py
row 0 = 'equals 0'
row 1 = 'equals 1'
```

and goes like that but every rows are `'equals 0'` why this can be

Comment: You're assigning the value of the column to `i`. So the final value is the last one in the iteration. To prove it, try running your loop with `go(3)` versus `go(4)`

Comment: Yes i understand it now but is there a way to surmount this? I could do that by creating a list but it takes too much time and memory. I would like to do it with generators. How can i do it with generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value to each row, however, doing this iteratively over a new column is clunky. You'd be better off mapping the new column off of the index of the old one:

```py
  GeneratorColumn
0               a
1               b
2               c
3               d
4               e
5               f
6               g

df['newcol'] = df.GeneratorColumn.index.map(lambda x: 'equals 0' if not x % 2 else 'equals 1')

  GeneratorColumn    newcol
0               a  equals 0
1               b  equals 1
2               c  equals 0
3               d  equals 1
4               e  equals 0
5               f  equals 1
6               g  equals 0
```

Where your lambda could be re-written like:

```py
def go(idx):
    if idx % 2:
        val = 'equals 1'
    else:
        val = 'equals 0'
    return val


df['newcol'] = df.GeneratorColumn.index.map(go)

  GeneratorColumn    newcol
0               a  equals 0
1               b  equals 1
2               c  equals 0
3               d  equals 1
4               e  equals 0
5               f  equals 1
6               g  equals 0
```